# SharePoint Online, javascript get user properties

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, client-object-model, cewp

I'm trying to get some user properties and alert them (I'm going to put them i labels later but just for now I'm using alert). I'm using a content editor with this code:

```
     SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js','SP.ClientContext',runthiscode);
    function runthiscode()
    {   
            SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.UserProfiles.js','SP.UserProfiles',getUserProperties);
    }
    var personProperties;
        function getUserProperties() {  

            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

            personProperties = peopleManager.getMyProperties();

            clientContext.load(personProperties);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFail);
        }

        function onRequestSuccess() {       

          alert(personProperties.get_displayName());
          alert(personProperties.get_pictureUrl());
          alert(personProperties.get_loginName());

        }

        function onRequestFail(sender, args) {
          alert("error msg");
        }
```

The alert with loginName doesn't work, why is that? Why can I get pictureUrl and displayName but no other properties? Is there any list of properties available for reference?

Comment: Try `get_accountName()`, I hope this will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method [SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager.getPropertiesFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj712745%28v=office.15%29.aspx) returns [SP.UserProfiles.PersonProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj712733%28v=office.15%29.aspx) object. 
You could find the list of properties for `PersonProperties` object [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj712733%28v=office.15%29.aspx#properties) and there is no property named `LoginName`.

Probably you need to retrieve property named `accountName`:

```
var value = SP.UserProfiles.PersonProperties.get_accountName()
```